# Making individual words / characters clickable by javascript

Tags: javascript

I am somewhat of a novice when it comes to Javascript, and I cannot find an answer to this question (or perhaps I am not searching for the right terms).  Is there a way to make a single word or character in an HTML < p > tag clickable so that a javascript function can act upon just that word or character, not the whole < p > tag?

thanks for the help.

Comment: wrap it in a span and add a click event

Comment: You can even analyze whole p content, if you find word you want, do something

Comment: would that mean if I wanted any text on the website to be clickable at any time each word and character would need their own span?

Answer (score 0):

As a previous commenter has mentioned, you can wrap your text in a span (or any inline element really), give the span an ID or class (or data attribute, whatever works for you in this case) - save the element to a JavaScript variable and use an event listener to listen for a click on the desired element.

```js
let clickableText = document.querySelector( "#clickable" );

clickableText.addEventListener( "click", function() {

  console.log( "Clicked!" );

})
```

```html
<p>This is my paragraph. Click <span id="clickable" style="font-weight: 600; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">THIS</span>.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by wrapping the clickable text inside a `<span>` element, like so:

```js
document.querySelector("#clickable").onclick = () => alert("You clicked the element");
```

```css
#clickable {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    This is a paragraph of text, with a <span id="clickable">clickable element</span>.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: would that mean if I wanted any text on the website to be clickable at any time each word and character would need their own span?

Comment: @MichaelShort If you want to make every word on the **entire website** clickable, you'd probably need to use JS to split up each paragraph into one-word spans, and attach the right event listeners to those spans. You might be able to use Lettering.js to do this for you: https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js/wiki/Wrapping-words-with-lettering%28%27words%27%29